Are chart patterns valid across gaps?
Bitcoin has a standard chart that is always going 24/7 365. It never closes. The CME has a bitcoin futures chart and it closes for the weekend. Many people know about 'CME gaps' and how the price tends to fill the gap if there is a gap in the closing price of the CME chart and the opening price of the CME gap. It doesn't always get filled, but it does more often than not.
Will the chart patterns formed across the gap still be valid when the market starts back up on Sunday evening? If the weekend price action invalidates a chart pattern that would work for the CME chart, will that chart pattern still be valid when the market opens back up on Monday?
